# How do you set a trap in sniper elite III

Tags: sniper-elite-3

How do you set a trap in sniper elite III?

Comment: The question body is intended for elaboration on the question's title, not for you to just copy paste the title into.

Answer (score 1):

A player on [this Steam forum](http://steamcommunity.com/app/238090/discussions/0/46476144861175549/) had the same issue, and an answer was posted:

> Press F. With the tripwire you will need to lay the mine then walk away a bit(you will see the green highlighted line that is the tripwire for that trap) and place it so it is in a path. There are Landmines, Trip Mines and S Mines. Press Q to bring up the wheel, select one of these and the I told you the other part. S Mines are larger infantry mines.

Here is [a video tutorial](https://youtu.be/wQF0pA4hBi8) explaining how to set up a perfect trap, using

> a dead body as a lure , bouncing betty mine as a method of kill trap , and a rock as a distraction